# requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql

requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user

```
public DataAccess()
        {
            ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CafeteriaDB"].ConnectionString;
        }

public bool RegisterUser(string UserName, string UserEmail, string UserPassword)
        {
            UserPassword = SimpleHash.ComputeHash(UserPassword);

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Users (Name, Role, Email, Password) values ('" + UserName + "', 'Salesman', '" + UserEmail + "', '" + UserPassword + "');", connection);
                connection.Open();

                int RowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (RowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
        }
```

and my app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="CafeteriaDB"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CafeteriaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Does the user have permissions in the DB server?  Check that

Comment: yes, its have permission

Comment: No it doesn't have permission. The error says so. You need to pursue that avenue. Do you know what `Integrated Security=SSPI;` means in the security string?

Comment: no i dont but, not SSPI generate the problem :/ i gave it the right permisson but throw another login failed = . The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount......